# Stock sample / voice acting request. (Or help finding the appropriate place)

Tags: voice-over, samples, electronic-music

I am searching for a sample of an older male, I imagine a 50 something Caucasian male speaking in a tone of voice of a military commander to his unit the words: "Keep 'em in the holding pattern." If the sample has transmitted through an authentic sketchy radio link, even better, or even through a cheap effect of one would be sufficient.

Does anyone have this sample (and rights to let me use in music), wet or dry? (I already plan to do the effects myself)

Alternatively, Where can I find this exact type of voice acting?

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to pay a little fee you could commission a recording. I haven't use the service before but I came across this service from the production of a video I saw.

http://voicebunny.com

Comment: Similarly there is http://www.fiverr.com/